# Kafka confluent with docker setup - mongodb connector

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I have downloaded confluent platform and setup the docker by using this link https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.2.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml. I have added mongodb connector(all.jar) file inside confluent_hub_components.
When I try to connect sink connector it not connecting my local mongodb uri. I am getting `error unable to connect` server. why I am getting this error?, What did I wrong? Error screenshot attached.[image]

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` refers to the Control Center container, not any external MongoDB server.

That compose file doesn't have any Mongo servers.